В тестовом магазине всё работало хорошо, но когда подключил реальный магазин ЮКасса стала возвращать ошибку
В тестовом магазине всё работало хорошо, но когда подключил реальный магазин, ЮКасса стала возвращать ошибку
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments
Сам код:
import yookassa
import config
from app import database as db
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import main


def create_payment():
    yookassa.Configuration.account_id = config.YK_id
    yookassa.Configuration.secret_key = config.YK_key

    payment = yookassa.Payment.create({
        "amount": {
            "value": 2000,
            "currency": "RUB"
        },
        "confirmation": {
            "type": "redirect",
            "return_url": 'https://t.me/HLSgamebot'
        },
        "description": "Оплата демо-версии игры",
        "capture": True
    })
    print(payment)
    url = payment.confirmation.confirmation_url

    return url, payment.id


Покажите, что вам в ответе на запрос от юкассы приходит
